# Evaluating ${my.property} as a SpEL expression within a @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

**Long story short:**

Is there a way to interpret the string resulting from `${my.property}` as a SpEL expression within a `@Value` annotation without using converters, e.g. something like `@Value("#{${my.property}}`)?

---

I have an abstract factory (simplified) that lets me build some common objects that are part of the configuration of my system.

```
@Component
public class Factory {
  public Product makeVal(int x) { return new Product(5); }
}
```

In order to be more flexible, I'd like to let users write SpEL expressions in the `app.properties` file, so that the factory can directly be accessed:

```
my.property = @Factory.makeVal(12)
```

Now, in the class needing this property, to achieve my goal I wrote the following code.

```
@Value("#{${my.property}}")
private Product obj;
```

I thought that `${my.property}` would be be macro-expanded and then evaluated by `#{}` as the corresponding SpEL expression, `@Factory.makeVal(12)` in the example above. Unfortunately, this wasn't the case, and loading the Spring context resulted in an error saying that it could not convert a string (the property's value `${my.property}`) to the destination type `Product`.

Now, I solved this by writing a class implementing `Converter<String, Product>`, but it's very convoluted as I need there to programmatically evaluate the string as a SpEL expression by instantiating the `ExpressionParser` and so on.

But is there a simpler solution? Is there a single SpEL expression to be put in `@Value` annotations that lets me simply evaluate `${my.property}` as a SpEL expression by itself, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it just a matter of replacing `@Factory` with `factory` in the property value. This test passes for me:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpelTest.Config.class })
public class SpelTest
{
    @Value("#{${my.property}}")
    Product _product;

    @Test
    public void evaluating_spel_from_property_value() throws Exception
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(1234, _product.value);
    }

    @Component
    public static class Factory
    {
        public Product makeVal(int x) { return new Product(x); }
    }

    public static class Product
    {
        public final int value;

        public Product(final int value) { this.value = value; }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SpelTest.class)
    public static class Config
    {
        @Bean
        public Factory factory() { return new Factory(); }

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer psc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            final MutablePropertySources sources = new MutablePropertySources();
            sources.addFirst(new MockPropertySource()
                .withProperty("my.property", 
                          "factory.makeVal(1234)"));
            psc.setPropertySources(sources);
            return psc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch, I was completely wrong. Apart from the fact that I forgot to mention I explicitly specified a bean name "Factory" rather than leaving the implicit "factory" one, it appears the original error I got was from a completely different annotation. Too tired, too tired XD I'll delete the question asap, as in fact it doesn't make any sense as it is. Thanks anyway :D