# Is there a way to bind to a value indirectly using SpEL - referencing SpEL expression property value

Tags: java, spring, properties, environment-variables

Currently, I have the following constructor definition, which takes values from a properties file:

```
public MongoMain(
        @Value("#{mongo.main.host}") String host, 
        @Value("${mongo.main.port}") Integer port,
        @Value("${mongo.main.dbname}") String dbName,
        @Value("${mongo.main.username}") String username,
        @Value("${mongo.main.password}") String password,
        @Value("${mongo.main.slaveok}") boolean slaveOk
        ) throws MongoException{
```

I want the option of using not a constant defined in the properties file, but referencing an environment variable. Is there a way to accomplish this by just modifying the properties file itself?

It currently has:

```
mongo.main.host=localhost
```

but I was hoping something like this might work:

```
mongo.main.host=#{systemProperties['MONGO_HOST']}
```

but it does not.

It seems like it might relate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465992/evaluating-my-property-as-a-spel-expression-within-a-value-annotation) question.

Comment: Are you using plain spring or spring-boot?

Comment: This is plain Spring.